# UIView sizing and opacity

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a UIView which when shown should cover a UIButton and a UILabel, however I am having a bunch of problems with it.

First of all the UIView is not covering the underneath button and label: 
[image: screenshot1]

Second, I added all the suggested constraints to the view and its components (a button and a picker view) but it still came out like this:

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Wait, so you want the picker view to cover the "Duration" label?

Comment: yes, because it pops up when the Notification button is pressed and it should cover both the button and the label

Comment: Can't you just hide it when the picker view is up?

Comment: yea that's what I'm gonna do, but it's just bizarre that the UIView doesn't cover whatever is underneath it.

Comment: The view's background color might simply just be set to [UIColor clearColor] use the view debugging tool in cases like this to see the view hierarchy visually, this is usually the case.